# jQuery validator does not respond

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've tried to use jQuery validator, and it seems like it just does not respond.
I'm trying to validate whether an image uploading form is not empty.
I've added the `if(jQuery)` section in order to check whether jQuery is actually included, and it is. 
I cannot figure out what makes it happen.  Any suggestion would be helpful.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jsFunc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>picLoc</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="hero-unit">
          <center>
             <h2>Upload a picture and find where exactly it was taken</h2>
             </br>
             <h2>It really works !</h2>
             </br>
             <form action="results.php" id="upload-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                  <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
                  <div>
                    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"/></span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload</button>
                  </div>
             </form>
          </center>
      </div>




      <hr>

      <footer></footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
if(jQuery)
{
    alert('included');
}
else
{
    alert('not included');
}

jQuery.validator.setDefaults(
{
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#upload-image').validate(
    {
        rules : 
        {
            pic : 
            {
                required : true,
                accept : "image/*"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Be careful... you are missing the `</div>` closing tag for `<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
pic: {
   required: true,
   accepted: "image/*"
}
```

The `rule` is called `accept`, not `accepted`.

See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#mimetype

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d5Fzc/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#upload-image').validate({
        rules: {
            pic: {
                required: true,
                accept: "image/*"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

**EDIT**:

I've put your newly updated code in this jsFiddle and it still works:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyYnb/

The code in your OP will not work, however, simply because you totally forgot to include the jQuery Validate plugin...

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jsFunc.js"></script>
```

Include the plugin...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js

And for the `accept` rule, you'll also need the `additional-methods.js` file...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I've checked the jsfiddle which seems to work but I still can upload an empty form for a reason I can't figure out yet

Comment: @Itamar, how do you mean "upload an empty form"?  If it's empty, why would you want to "upload" it?  Your rules say that this field is `required` which means it will not allow the form to be submited with this field left empty.  If you want this to be optional, then remove the `required` rule.

Comment: that's exactly the point - I don't want that users will be able to send an empty form - but after I've fixed the code as you suggested , I'm still able to send an empty form.

Comment: @Itamar, As you recognized already, [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5Fzc/) containing your code from the OP is working properly, so what's causing the problem?  Your OP's code also contains the `debug: true` option, which would completely block the normal form submit; is there any other part of this code you have not shown us?

Comment: I've now updated the question and it contains all the code from the page that contains the upload form. Thanks for helping !

Comment: I've offered 50 credit points for the problem , I really ain't got a clue about what's wrong

Comment: @Itamar, you did not "include" the jQuery Validate plugin anyplace in your OP.  That's why it's only working fine in the jsFiddle.  See my edits.

Comment: Thanks again , I've added both files - jquery additional methods and jquery validate, and I'm still able to submit an empty form... any other suggestion ?

Comment: @Itamar, I have no other suggestions.  Obviously, you must not be including them properly or it would be working exactly the same as demonstrated here:  http://jsfiddle.net/kyYnb/

Comment: I've upadted the code once again , now it contains the linking to the necessary files . I still don't see what's wrong...thanks for the help

Comment: @Itamar, I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted and [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyYnb/) proves it's working.

Comment: @Itamar, this is getting somewhat frustrating.  You've posted three different versions of your code, each one with a significant error that would totally break it... now it's up to you to make sure your code exactly matches the good code in the working jsFiddle.  Are you getting any JavaScript console errors?

Comment: I've solved the problem :) It was actually the if(jQuery) check that messed it all up

Comment: @Itamar, I'm relieved.  Good deal.

Comment: I'll be able to give you the bounty in 22 hours . If i haven't done it by then , don't hesitate and comment here so i'll notice that. Thanks once again !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28459/discussion-between-itamar-and-sparky)

Answer (score 1):

`$document` in `$document.ready(function()...` should be `$(document)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload-image').validate({
        rules : {
            pic : {
                required : true,
                accepted : "image/*"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

**After you edited your question:**

Also you forgot to close the div tag in your form:

```
<form action="results.php" id="upload-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="btn btn-file">
                <span class="fileupload-new">
                    Select image
                </span>
                <span class="fileupload-exists">
                    Change
                </span>
                <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"/>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">
                Remove
            </a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">
                Upload
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful... you are missing the `</div>` closing tag for `<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `sys\jsFunc.js` is where you have your code for jQuery validator initialization.
If that is the case, the problem is that your JavaScript include order.

### Yours

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jsFunc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

### Fix

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jsFunc.js"></script>
```

#### JavaScript file include order:

1. jquery.js
2. bootstrap.js
3. jquery.validate.js
4. additional-methods.js // this has a dependency on **jquery.validate.js**
5. sys/jsFunc.js

I tested it with the new include order on my computer, and it works :-)